# focus() Doesn't Work When Trigger Element is Last on Page

Tags: javascript, dom

If I've got a form where the submit button is the last focusable element on the page:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

And I want to maintain focus inside the form even if the user tries to tab away:

```
form.submit.addEventListener('blur',() => {
    form.text.focus();
});
```

Focus doesn't return to the text element, it moves on to the browser's address bar. However, if I add another focusable element after the form:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <button>Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Then everything works as expected. What's happening here?

Comment: If you put `console.log("blur")` in the event listener, do you see the log message when it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Barmar Yep, console message fires on blur